# Web2py Python split rows based on true/false from database result

Tags: python, for-loop, split, web2py

I have the following code in web2py/python:

```
{{for row in db(db.t_problems.id==db.t_problems(request.args(0))).select(): }}
```

Which grabs all of the rows, as I need them to be. The rows are actual python results, which when I print them out are:

```
>>> testFunction(2, 3, 4) True >>> testFunction(2, 1, 4) False >>> legalTriangles(-1, -1, -1) False
```

(when you do a raw output, this is what you get:)

```
>>> testFunction(2, 3, 4)\r\nTrue >>> testFunction(2, 1, 4)\r\nFalse >>> legalTriangles(-1, -1, -1)\r\nFalse
```

What I need to do is remove the >>>, and have the testFunction(X,Y,Z) in one variable result and the True/False in another. I thought this might work, but the loop only strips the \r\n, not puts them in a new variable to work with:

```
ios = row.f_tests.split('>>>') #results are now the testFunctions without the >>>
for io in ios:
     i = io.split("\r\n")
```

So the result becomes:

```
testFunction(2, 3, 4)True testFunction(2, 1, 4)False testFunction(-1, -1, -1)False
```

But what I need is...

```
func1 = testFunction(2, 3, 4)
res1 = True
func2 = testFunction(2, 1, 4)
res2 = False
```

So I can put them into a table. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Note, you should do your db select in the controller and pass the result to the view.

Comment: I will, but am still learning web2py, so I put the actual code in the page first, then when I get it right, move it to the controller. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In raw python, it would be,

```
s = ">>> testFunction(2, 3, 4)\r\nTrue >>> testFunction(2, 1, 4)\r\nFalse >>> legalTriangles(-1, -1, -1)\r\nFalse"
for func, result in [i.splitlines() for i in s.split(">>>") if i]:
    print "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (func.strip(), result.strip())
```

Result:

```
<tr><td>testFunction(2, 3, 4)</td><td>True</td></tr>
<tr><td>testFunction(2, 1, 4)</td><td>False</td></tr>
<tr><td>legalTriangles(-1, -1, -1)</td><td>False</td></tr>
```

You should be able to translate it to the template or "view" language of web2py. I see [from here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05) that it supports the for-loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Am not sure why I couldn't get it before, but your code worked beautifully. (And for some reason, I've always had a problem with Python loops, not with other languages.)